# Got Exception when trying to implement SOAP webservice

Tags: soap

I am trying to implement a simple program in Eclipse using SOAP Webservice I am getting this error.Can sombody help me for this. 
Exception occurred during code generation for WSDL  : org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: No operation found in the portType element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In wsdl,    the  element can be compared to a function library (or a module, or a class) in a traditional programming language.
And operation element defines each operation (methods), that the port exposes.

According to the error you have, class i.e portType but it has no methods (operations) to be performed. following is sample for port type in wsdl.

```
<portType name="glossaryTerms">
 <operation name="getTerm">
    <input message="getTermRequest"/>
    <output message="getTermResponse"/>
 </operation>
</portType>
```